# Any way to access Calico network by non-Calico nodes

Tags: calico

I am very new to Calico and Calico networking, so far I went through the Calico docs.
My question is, is there any way to access **Calico network** by **non-Calico** nodes?
Went through all the docs, but haven't found any solution, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation here https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.6/usage/external-connectivity , you will find, it is mentioned there in `Inbound connectivity` part:-
`BGP peering into your network` infrastructure, or using `orchestrator specific options`..

But if you want to get `simple` connectivity, a better option is to run `calico/node` service and `calicoctl` command line tool can be used to launch `calico/node` container, 
which is configured to connect to the **datastore** being used, on a **non-calico** node.
That will cause the routes to be distributed to the host and then it would be able to access the workloads.
Found similar ref: https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/858
Hope this helps you

Comment: Yes understood now.. Thanks :)  How could I missed that